# Trouble deploying java web app to Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, deployment

I have been trying to deploy my java app to Heroku for 2 days. 
I do everything the same that people do in theirs tutorials. But something is wrong. 
How fix it ?

here is heroku application logs

```
2016-12-18T19:07:22.740701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port 37825 target/*.war`
2016-12-18T19:07:25.592632+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-12-18T19:07:25.599057+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2016-12-18T19:07:25.599116+00:00 app[web.1]: Unrecognized option: --port
2016-12-18T19:07:25.599120+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
2016-12-18T19:07:25.599120+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
2016-12-18T19:08:20.220329+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-journey-44108.herokuapp.com request_id=229e3557-e7c8-4084-9000-c14e7b0128ad fwd="109.201.209.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-12-18T19:08:20.956253+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-journey-44108.herokuapp.com request_id=fe14db1e-c45f-4d80-9e47-d18e9d3d544d fwd="109.201.209.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

plugin in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.2.7.v20150116</version>
                                <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**and Procfile**

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Comment: "2016-12-18T19:07:25.599116+00:00 app[web.1]: Unrecognized option: --port" - read the error messages.

Comment: i see but i can't figure out how fix it. Google nothing knows about it

Comment: Nothing?  I doubt that.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support

Comment: Try this: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target*.jar.  Java is not node.js.

Comment: yes. I've read it a few minutes ago but it doen't help me.Sorry.

Comment: I'm guessing that the stuff I found will sort you out.  "2 days"?  I found this in 2 minutes.

Comment: i tried different ways and even tried use other hosting service like Openshift.
i can't deploy my app anyway

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.  I guess you'll just have to give up.  Google can't help you.  Did you try the change I found for you?

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone has solution??

Answer (score 1):

I have deployed only node.js applications in a free account without plugins on heroku so far. And what I had to do is to take a port assigned by heroku instead of a static one which you seem to specify by

```
--port 37825
```

Perhaps this is the problem? The error seems to be port-related. Try to google for "dynamic port heroku java"

Answer (score 0):

Your `Procfile` should probably be:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Note the `-jar` instead of `-cp`

Comment: how to use -javaagent:heroku-javaagent-2.0.jar=stdout=true,lxmem=true option with this ?